# Ecto fuzzy match on multiple words

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, fuzzy-search

In my DB (PostgreSQL) I added the `fuzzystrmatch` extension and have been trying to use the `levenshtein` function to match items. It does not work how I would like it to when the columns are strings of multiple words.

The code:

```
  def fuzzy_search(query_string, threshold \\ 4) do
    query_string = query_string |> String.downcase()

    query =
      from item in MyApp.Item,
        where:
          levenshtein(item.name, ^query_string, ^threshold) or
          levenshtein(item.quote, ^query_string, ^threshold),
        order_by:
          fragment(
            "LEAST (?, ?)",
            levenshtein(item.name, ^query_string),
            levenshtein(item.quote, ^query_string)
          )

    MyApp.Repo.all(query)
  end
```

The code works (levenshtein is just a macro for a quoted query) but my problem lies with the `name` column of these items. Item names such as "Lodestone Ammolet" don't match a search for "lodestone" as the second word makes too much of a difference.

If I increase the threshold it just provides too many matches that aren't as relevant. What's the best approach to solve this? I could only think of trying to `split` the name on spaces and levenshtein match on the result, but I'm unsure of how to do that.

Comment: You might try to generate several matches with [`split_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) and join them with boolean `OR`.

Comment: hmm this sounds like what I would need but it seems `split_part` takes in an index for the row to return and there are some items that consist of 2, 3, or 4 words. I could try just doing all 4, idk what the levenshtein of an empty row would return

Comment: “idk what the levenshtein of an empty row would return”—neither do I. How about opening the `psql` console and _try_?